# El video grabado con python utilizando pyautogui, va acelerado con respecto al tiempo real, como si se grabara en x1.50

Tags: python, python-3.x, video

Estoy realizando un programa que graba un determinado tiempo la pantalla, sacando un clip.
Grabo y creo el video, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema viene a la hora de reproducirlo, ya que el video se ve mas rápido de lo que debería, ya intente cambiar los tiempos `

```
import cv2
import pyautogui
import numpy
from collections import deque
buffer_size = 30 * 60

screenSize = (1360, 768)
fileName = "videoPruebaRECORD.avi"
videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter(fileName, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID"), 30, screenSize)

# Inicializa el búfer circular utilizando deque
frame_buffer = deque(maxlen=buffer_size)

# Función para capturar y escribir un frame
def capture_and_write_frame():
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    videoWriter.write(frame)
    frame_buffer.append(frame)

# Bucle principal para grabar constantemente
while True:
    capture_and_write_frame()

    if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:  # 33 ms es aproximadamente 30 fps
        break

# Liberar el objeto cv2.VideoWriter
videoWriter.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Pero se sigue reproduciendo de la misma manera, espero alguien pueda orientarme hacia alguna solucion para que se pueda ver el video en x1.00, de antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Tenés que hacer que la captura se haga "cada x tiempo", si no, lo hace "lo antes posible" y la velocidad del video podría variar o ser una no esperada. la división 1/60 te va a dar la duración en segundos de un fotograma (en el caso de 60 fps). Podés también usar el modulo time (no uses time.sleep) para medir el tiempo transcurrido desde la ultima captura.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que pyautogui es capaz de generar 30 capturas por segundo en tu plataforma? En general es bastante lento, en mi caso consigue 50-60 capturas por segundo en Linux con Mutter como DM (gnome-screenshot como backend), pero depende de la plataforma. Si es capaz, aun tienes que tener en cuenta el tiempo de ejecución de `capture_and_write_frame()`, debes insertar un frame cada 1/30 s, no esperar 1/30 s tras insertar uno para empezar a generar el siguiente.

Comment: Que el video se vea "acelerado" es síntoma de que no se están generando suficientes frames para permitir una reproducción a 30FPS, es como si un video grabado a 20 FPS lo reproduces a 30FPS. Por cierto, cv2.waitKey no funciona sin una ventana de opencv abierta.

Comment: Ooo claro, muchas gracias, entonces buscare alguna alternativa para tomar las capturas, tiene sentido que se vea acelerado porque no toma todas las capturas que debería de tomar. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Los fps que le indicas a `cv2.VideoWriter` especifican a cuantos frames por segundo se reproducirá luego el video.

Para que el video se ajuste al tiempo real es imprescindible que insertes un frame cada 1/FPS segundos exactos o al menos lo mas preciso posible, asegurándote que el numero de frames final del video sera *fps * segundos de duración*.

En tu código no te aseguras de esto, si especificas 30 fps pero el proceso solo es capaz de generar 15 fps el video durara al final la mitad del tiempo real grabado y se vera acelerado 2x.

Si generas mas frames de los necesarios tendrás el problema opuesto, el video durará más tiempo que la grabación real y se "reproducirá a cámara lenta".

PyAutogui no es muy eficiente a la hora de generar capturas de pantalla, en mi caso con el equipo que lo he probado es capaz de generar 50-60 capturas por segundo en Linux con Mutter como DM (gnome-screenshot como backend), pero en otro SO, equipo y resolución esto puede variar enormemente. Lo mas probable es que en tu caso PyAutogui no sea capaz de generar esos 30 fps. Ademas, tienes que tener en cuenta que no debes esperar 1 / fps segundos entre que generas una captura e inicias la generacion de otra, la generación de la captura (llamadas a `pyautogui.screenshot()`, `cv2.cvtColor`, `videoWriter.write()`, etc) tarda un tiempo en procesarse y hay que tenerlo en cuenta.

Una opción en casos como este es mover la generación de la captura a un proceso/hilo y dejar el proceso principal solo para insertar los frames cuando corresponda. Si el subproceso no es capaz de generar los suficientes fps, se puede insertar el ultimo generado, esto creara "lag" pero la velocidad de reproducción y la duración del video se mantendrán.

Te dejo un ejemplo de implementación algo tosco pero que funciona razonablemente bien y muestra lo que digo:

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.managers

import time

import cv2
import numpy
import pyautogui


FILE_NAME = "videoPruebaRECORD.avi"
FRAME_RATE = 30

def get_screenshot_info():
    sdata = numpy.array(pyautogui.screenshot())
    return sdata.shape, sdata.dtype, sdata.nbytes

sshape, sdtype, snbyes = get_screenshot_info()


def get_screenshots_task(sm, lock, stop_event):
    data = numpy.ndarray(sshape, dtype=sdtype, buffer=sm.buf)
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        screenshot = numpy.array(pyautogui.screenshot())
        with lock:
            cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB, data)
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    with multiprocessing.managers.SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
        video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
            FILE_NAME,
            cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID"),
            FRAME_RATE,
            pyautogui.size()
            )
        
        sm = smm.SharedMemory(size=snbyes)
        data = numpy.ndarray(sshape, dtype=sdtype, buffer=sm.buf)
        lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        stop_event = multiprocessing.Event()
        child = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=get_screenshots_task,
            args=(sm, lock, stop_event)
            )
        child.start()
        
        try:
            start_time = time.monotonic()
            frames = 0
            while True:
                if ((time.monotonic() - start_time) * FRAME_RATE) >= frames:
                    with lock:
                        video_writer.write(data)
                    frames += 1
                    #print(f"FPS: {int(frames / (time.monotonic() - start_time))}")

                    
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            video_writer.release()
            stop_event.set()
```

La grabación se detiene con <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

A pesar de que liberamos al proceso principal de la carga de generar y procesar la captura, este tienen un limite también. En mi caso, en el mismo equipo son unos 350 fps máximos.